# How to change the download folder of Microsoft Edge under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm using [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/windows/microsoft-edge) in Windows 10, but [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/windows/microsoft-edge) doesn't have the option to change the download directory.

I can change the main Download directory to other drive, but what I really want is to have both **Google Chrome** and **Microsoft Edge** folder inside of the main **Download** folder.

For example I would like to have:

`D:\Downloads\Google Chrome`

and

`D:\Downloads\Microsoft Edge`

What I really want is to directly Download to `D:\Downloads\Microsoft Edge` and not to `D:\Downloads`.

How do I change the default download folder for [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/windows/microsoft-edge)?

Comment: Why not just have IE go to `\Downloads` and Chrome go to `\Downloads\Chrome`? It'll achieve the same result.

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect that your question is about Microsoft Edge (what you called "the new Internet Explorer"). It's not called Internet Explorer anymore. Internet Explorer still exists, Microsoft Edge is a new browser by Microsoft.

Comment: @MichaelFrank it's not what I really want, what I want is to have both `D:\Downloads\Google Chrome` and `D:\Downloads\Microsoft Edge` in different directories on the same `D:\Downloads\` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:** Close Microsoft Edge browser, if it’s running.

**Step 2:** Open Registry Editor. To open it, type `regedit` in Start search box or Run command box and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image: image 1]

Click Yes button when you see User Account Control dialog.

**Step 3:** In the Registry Editor, navigate to the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main
```

[image: image 2]

**Step 4:** On the right-side, right-click to reveal the context menu, click New, click String Value. Rename the newly created String value to `Default Download Directory`.

[image: image 3]

Double-click on the newly created Default Download Directory, replace the default path in value data box with the path to the new download location. That’s it!

For instance, if you want to make `F:\ISO\Windows 10` as the new download directory, then enter the same in the Value data box and then click OK button.

[image]

[image]

**Tip:** If you want easily copy a folder path, simply right-click on the folder while holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, and then click Copy as path option. You can then paste this path anywhere you want by either pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or right-clicking and then clicking Paste option.

**Step 5:** Launch Edge browser, click the Hub icon (see picture), and then click Downloads to check the new download location. Note that files will be automatically downloaded to the newly added download location and you will not get an option to change the location while downloading files.

[image]

**Source:** http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-default-download-location-in-microsoft-edge/

Comment: Thank you @Kristian for your answer. It's a outrage Microsoft Edge don't have Download Option Directory change.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto Yeah, it's a very basic option to want to change. I agree it should be a user changable option and not require registry edit. I am hoping Microsoft will add it at some point.

Comment: True! But why do you think they keep this as it is @Kristian?

Comment: The folks on the Windows Insider program have been testing a version of Edge that allows you to choose the default location and to prompt for a location.  This feature is expected to be in the next release of Edge which should be available in late July with the Anniversary Update to Windows 10